“multidimensional expansion” with brace expansion in Bash?
I think my use case is best illustrated with a concrete example, say with imagemagick:
magick \( source_file_A1.jpg source_file_A2.jpg +append \) \
\( source_file_B1.jpg source_file_B2.jpg +append \) \
-append target_file.jpg

This command, for those that do not know appends these four source files in a 2×2 grid. Of course this process can be simplified in Bash with:
magick \( source_file_A{1,2}.jpg +append \) \
\( source_file_B{1,2}.jpg +append \) -append target_file.jpg

But this of course still has duplication of effort. Is there some kind of brace expansion way to expand to this part:
\( source_file_A{1,2}.jpg +append \) \( source_file_B{1,2}.jpg +append \)

That should ideally not include any duplication. This is of course especially useful when say a 5×5 matrix be required and one wants to use some kind of {A..E} trick here.

You can't use a trick with braces due to the surrounding text. You can construct the command as an array using a loop
# build the command
cmd=( magick )
for x in {A,B}; do
    cmd+=( '(' source_file_${x}{1,2}.jpg +append ')' )
done
cmd+=( -append target_file.jpg )

# inspect the command
declare -p cmd

# and execute it
"${cmd[@]}"

